# JSF snippet to center an image in a panel grid

Tags: jsf

I am trying to write some JSF code that centers an image in a panel grid.  The simple approach would appear to be:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" style="text-align:center">
  <h:graphicImage value="/path/to/image.png" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

but this approach does not seem to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use div with align=center

Or use CSS:

JSF

```
<h:panelGrid styleClass="centered">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>


CSS

.centered {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
```